# Argument is not a function, got undefined

Tags: php, angularjs, mysqli

Tengo un error por mas que he cambiado mi `controller` tengo el mismo problema.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("dashLot.php")
        .then(function (response) {$scope.lots = response.data.records;});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-content" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
   <table class="table table-striped">
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>Nombre</th>
         <th>Apellido</th>
         <th>Otro</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="lot in lots">
         <td>{{lot.a}}</td>
         <td>{{lot.b}}</td>
         <td>{{lot.c}}</td>
         
       </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
```

Ahora si se fijan bien esto llama a un PHP el cual deseo retornar todos los datos que estén en la base de datos.

```
$db = new ezSQL_mysql(DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);
try {
    $result = $db->get_results("select * from tblbilllandingtmp;");

    if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
        sleep(2);
        echo json_encode([
            'success' => true,
            'result' => $result
        ]);

    } else {

        echo json_encode([
            'success' => error]);
        throw new Exception($strRes);
    }
}catch(Exception $ex){

    die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());

}
return $result;
```

Si me pudieran ayudar se los agradecería

Comment: Te pregunto ya que no lo veo, donde tienes el `ng-app`??? podrías poner el HTML completo, ya que creo que eso es lo que te falta.

Comment: ¿Y en que parte del código te sale el mensaje de error?

Comment: Y despues de hacer lo que dice Carlos, puedes trata de probar chequeando esta linea `response.data.records;` porque creo que debes es usar `response.data;`

Comment: `$e->getMessage()` debe ser `$ex->getMessage()`?

Answer (score -1):

Intenta cambiar

```
return $result;
```

Por

```
echo json_encode($result);
```